# single quotes not working in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, nodemon

I'd like to get my package.json to be able to run using the command npm run test-watch on Windows 10 with npm 5.5.1. In my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha server/**/*.test.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test'"
  }
```

However, I this interpretes the code strangely to have a single quote in there. I'm actually following a Udemy course so it appears to work for the instructor. However, here is the output I get:

```
PS D:\courses\node-course\node-todo-api> npm run test-watch

> todo-api@1.0.0 test-watch D:\courses\node-course\node-todo-api
> nodemon --exec 'npm test'

[nodemon] 1.14.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `'npm test'`
''npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What do I need to change to get this to work? It appears to be keeping the quotes on the string. I can't seem to get around it though. When I run the command directly, it works:

```
PS D:\courses\node-course\node-todo-api> nodemon --exec 'npm test'
[nodemon] 1.12.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `npm test`

> todo-api@1.0.0 test D:\courses\node-course\node-todo-api
> mocha server/**/*.test.js



started on port 3000
  Post /todos
    √ should create a new todo (50ms)


  1 passing (1s)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, the operating system and shell can cause a massive headache when using npm. Some things work on one computer and some on another.

Both of these should work on Windows 10 though:

```
"test-watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm test\""
"test-watch": "nodemon --exec npm test"
```

Comment: Thanks... Can't believe I couldn't figure that one out LOL now that it is so easy...

Comment: Is there a way to get the command to work regardless of what system and shell are being used?

Comment: @cjsimon I think not using single quotes is the way to go to get it working on both *nix and Windows. Use "". According to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) page using three backslashes might be the best option (for some reason).