# Protractor option does not work in package.json script

Tags: protractor, package.json, cucumberjs

The following command works as expected:

```
protractor --cucumberOpts.tags='not @tag1' conf.js
```

Now I want to add this command as a `script` to `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "my-script": "protractor --cucumberOpts.tags='not @tag1' conf.js"
}
```

Running the command `npm run my-script` gives me the following error:

```
Usage: protractor [configFile] [options]
configFile defaults to protractor.conf.js
The [options] object will override values from the config file.
See the reference config for a full list of options.

Options:
  ...

Error: Error: more than one config file specified
```

Why is that?

Both of the commands seem to be identical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [single quotes not working in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104380/single-quotes-not-working-in-package-json)

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate but can understand how the root cause was not easy to spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually a protractor issue. I was able to recreate this issue and resolved it by using escaped doubles quotes in that script string like so.

```
"scripts": {
    "my-script": "protractor --cucumberOpts.tags=\"not @tag1\" conf.js"
}
```

This issue (apparently) is to do with how node handles single quotes on different operating systems. There is some more info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104380/single-quotes-not-working-in-package-json) question.

Comment: Thank you. I'd never thought the quotes could be the problem.