# Protractor - 'More than one config specified' error when tests are run via npm run but only if --capabilities.chromeOptions.binary param is used

Tags: javascript, npm, parameters, protractor, package.json

I have a problem with running protractor scripts defined in **package.json** on Windows 10 machine - locally and on virtual machine.

I have **package.json** and **protractor.conf.js** with standard content.

Protractor script in **package.json** looks as follows:

`"run-tests": "protractor protractor.conf.js --baseUrl=https://some-website --capabilities.chromeOptions.binary='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'",`

However, when I run it with `npm run run-tests` I receive error:

```
Error: more than one config file specified
```

Removing *--capabilities.chromeOptions.binary* param fixes the issue, but I do need it on my virtual machine.

Similarly, when I execute the full command directly in terminal tests are run without a hitch, i.e.:
`protractor protractor.conf.js --baseUrl=https://some-website --capabilities.chromeOptions.binary='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'`

I noticed that when I use **npm run** backslash characters in the path displayed in terminal are already escaped:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

However, even quadrupling backslashes i.e. writing:
`'C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\Application\\\\chrome.exe'`
does not help with the problem.

Do you have any ideas? Or do you perhaps know alternative method to pass the said value to binary param in protractor.conf.js?

Edit: running terminal in administrator mode does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution here:

[Protractor option does not work in package.json script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478786/protractor-option-does-not-work-in-package-json-script)

Basically you have to use escaped double quotes enveloping path to file. So it goes like this:

`"{some other stuff} --capabilities.chromeOptions.binary=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\""`