# How to configure ESlint to work both Mac and WIndows machines

Tags: eslint

I have a Nodejs project which uses ESLint to keep consistency. 
On my Mac machine, I have no troubles all works bur on Windows I got this error

```
No files matching the pattern "'./*'" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
```

My setup for ESLint is

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "prettier"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "linebreak-style": "off"
    }
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "new-architecture-solution",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "prod": "node -r esm server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -r esm server.js",
    "debug": "ndb nodemon -r esm server.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx --quiet",
    "fix": "eslint './*' --fix",
    "prettier": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,css}"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "package.json",
    "package-lock.json",
    "combined.log",
    "swagger.json",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "lint-staged": {
    "./**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "npm run prettier",
      "npm run lint --color",
      "npm run fix",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
```

I'm unable to find asolution and I would like to have it work in both my machines

Comment: just remove singlequotes from eslint './*' --fix

Comment: Not worked on my mac now saying the same error as on windows :(

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it yet on Windows, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104731/7018894) replacing the single quotes with `\"` might do the trick. I've tried it on my Mac and it seems to work properly.

Edit: confirmed to work on Windows machines as well.