# Command chain in package.json scripts throws and error

Tags: javascript, cypress, package.json

I have a problem, where I defined a script in my package.json and call it with "yarn my-script".

"my-script" contains a chain of commands to run my cypress tests, lets say

```
"scripts": {
    "my-script": ""start-server-and-test 'yarn start' http://localhost:8080 'yarn cypress run'""
},
```

When I call this chain manually like this

`yarn start-server-and-test 'yarn start' http://localhost:8080 'yarn cypress run'`

everything works fine, but a error is thrown, when I try to call the chain via package.json script like this

`yarn my-script`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is the string delimited by two quotes on each side?

Comment: Nevermind, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104380/single-quotes-not-working-in-package-json) solved it. I need to use double quotes and escape them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [single quotes not working in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104380/single-quotes-not-working-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could chain them with double ampersand `&&`

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "my-script": "start http://localhost:8080 && cypress run"
}
```

then run `yarn my-script`