# How to replace text in file with npm run scripts in package.json Windows OS

Tags: windows, perl, sed, next.js, package.json

I developed chrome extension using Nextjs and My develop environment is Windows.
But I have issue when build and export the app and load it on extension because cannot load extension with file or directory name _next.
So need to move the _next file to 'assets' file and replace '_next' to 'assets' in index.html.
I installed sed-4.2.1 and added these lines in "scripts" of package.json

```
"scripts": {
"build": "next build && next export && npm run prepare",
"prepare": "move out/_next out/assets && sed -i 's/\\/_next/\\/assets/g' out/index.html"}
```

But 'sed' not worked with this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

So, I tried to run 'perl -p -i -e's/_next/assets/g' out/index.html' on cmd and it worked well.
But I added line in scripts, it has not worked.

```
"scripts": {
"build": "next build && next export && npm run prepare",
"prepare": "move out/_next out/assets && perl -p -i -e's/_next/assets/g' out/index.html"}
```

What's the reason?
And what is the best way to replace text???

Comment: See also [single quotes not working in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48104380/2173773). Try replace single quotes with escaped double quotes

Comment: Yes! it works well with 'sed'! Thank you!

Comment: But do you know why 'perl' doesn't run on scripts?